# How to include a variable in regular expression as part of pattern matching using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a variable that stores the device name say `$dev_to_connect = "XYZ keyboard"`. I want it to include it in my regular expression as part of pattern matching. I have tried using `\Q..\E`. But i found it not helpful.

The regular expression i am using is `'Dev:(\d)\r\n\tBdaddr:(..):(..):(..):(..):(..):(..)\r\n\tName:\Q$device_to_connect\E'`

I want the `\Q$device_to_connect\E` part of regular expression to be matched with the original value in the variable.

Comment: i need to use groups inorder to get the matchlist. So, i want it variable to be included in pattern matching without any modification to existing regular expression

Answer (score 3):

Single quotes don't interpolate. You could use double-quotes, but that would require a lot of escaping. `qr//` is designed for this very purpose.

```
qr/Dev:(\d)...Name:\Q$device_to_connect\E/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your variable names mixed up. You define $dev_to_connect but you reference $device_to_connect in your regex. If you fix that using a variable in a regex is straightforward:

```
$var = 'foo';
if ($_ =~ /$var/) {
  print "Got '$var'!\n";
}
```

Here is a snippet out of one of my scripts that works:

```
if ($ctlpt =~ /$owner/) {
  ($opt_i) && print "$prog: INFO: $psd is on $ctlpt.\n";
} else {
  print "$prog: WARNING: $psd is on $ctlpt, and not on $owner.\n";
}
```

Comment: I have tried this way of regex in my expression and it doesn't work

Comment: It does work (see edit). I recommend you start debugging your regex. Start with a regex as simple as possible for testing. And @ikegami is right. You can't have your variable in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have to find double words in a document, this is how to do it:

`\b(\w+)\s+\1\b`

**And here is the anatomy:**

```
<!--
\b(\w+)\s+\1\b

Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks

Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\w+)»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match the same text as most recently matched by capturing group number 1 «\1»
Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
-->
```

---

Calling the group number is only the way to call/include a preceding group in pattern. Hope this halp. Visit [here](http://www.regexbuddy.com/library.html?) for reference.

Comment: what you are saying is to search for "word". But it is not my requirement. I want a string stored in a variable to be matched as part of regular expression which i mentioned above

Comment: I am not saying exactly what you want, but rather showing you a way to achieve your goal. The example show that a way to include first group in your match.